# Vala: Reading UTF-8 string from bytes not recognizing multibyte characters

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8, vala

For the application that I am currently working on, I am required to read UTF-8 encoded strings from a binary file. These strings are not null-terminated, but rather are prefaced with a byte specifying their length.

When I attempt to read in such a string, all multibyte UTF-8 characters become `?`. Find below a sample:

```
public void main(string[] args) {
  File file = File.new_for_path("test.bin");
  DataInputStream instream = new DataInputStream(file.read());
  uint8[] chars = new uint8[instream.read_byte()];
  instream.read(chars);
  print(@"$((string) chars)\n");
}
```

This is, of course, a stripped sample. The actual binary files in question are encrypted, which is not reflected here. If I use this with a sample file test.bin that contains the byte sequence `09 52 C3 AD 61 73 74 72 61 64`, or `Ríastrad` prefaced with its byte length in UTF-8. The expected output is thus `Ríastrad`, but the actual output is `R?astrad`.

Might anyone be able to shed some light on the problem and, perhaps, a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `Intl.setlocale ();` to your code:

```
public void main(string[] args) {
  Intl.setlocale ();
  File file = File.new_for_path("test.bin");
  DataInputStream instream = new DataInputStream(file.read());
  uint8[] chars = new uint8[instream.read_byte()];
  instream.read(chars);
  print(@"$((string) chars)\n");
}
```

The default locale for `print ()` is the C locale, which is US ASCII. Any character outside the US ASCII character range is presented as a `?`. Using `Intl.setlocale ();` sets the locale to be the same as the machine running the program.

Comment: Thank you very much -- that did exactly what I needed! I was focused entirely on the string side of things and completely neglected the other, in this case more important side. Not a mistake I'll be making again!

Comment: @AlThomas Where did you find the information that the `Intl.setlocale()` was the solution?

Comment: @WhyWhat By my own research. Vala compiles to the C ABI, so I understand the C runtime environment and also about character encodings. The C standard library setlocale() is described in more detail in the POSIX documentation: [https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/setlocale.html](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/setlocale.html)